# Send NumPy image to channel without saving with discord.py

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, discord.py

I am well aware of how to send an image from a path from a Discord bot. Yet, I am working on a bot which handles image manipulation, and saving the image after I have manipulated said image, to then be opened again by the Discord bot seems unpractical.

Is there any way to send the image generated without saving it? The image is in the form of a three-dimensional NumPy array.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in binary data when initializing [`discord.File`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.File) by using [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO).
Also see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=io.BytesIO#how-do-i-upload-an-image.